# Unusual behaviour with booleans in javascript

Tags: javascript, boolean, bitwise-and

While working with booleans in javascript, I have noticed an uncertainty:

```
"false" && true  //this gives output true
false && true //this gives output false
```

Can I somebody explain this behaviour?

Comment: `"false"` is a non-empty string, which is truth-y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing unusual about it. The `&&` operator is short-circuited logical AND. Both conditions need to be `true` for the entire expression to be `true` and if any condition is `false`, the entire operation is `false` and the rest of the conditions are not tested.

In the first example, `"false"` is not the Boolean `false`, it's the String `"false"`, which is a valid "something", or a ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value, so it evaluates to `true`.

```js
console.log("false" && true);  //this gives output true
```

In the second example, the actual Boolean `false` is used, which (as stated) causes the entire operation to be false.

```js
console.log(false && true); //this gives output false
```

Answer (score 1):

Because string other than empty string is a truthy value that's why the first expression resolves to true

Answer (score 1):

non-null/undefined/empty strings in JavaScript are `true` for boolean logic purposes. In the second case, false && true is logicall false

Answer (score 1):

Because `"false"` isn't a boolean, it's a string.  Regardless of what text that string contains and how a human may intuitively interpret the meaning of that text, it's a string like any other.

And any non-empty string is ["truthy"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy), in that when evaluated in a boolean fashion (coerced) it results in a `true` value.